# google maps move marker with lat/lng from ajax success returned data

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to move marker/map on interval with lat/long coords from sql db.

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41,14);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatLng,
        scrollwheel: false,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: false
});

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function getCoords() {

$.ajax({
url: "../ajaxscript.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
foo : "bar"
},
dataType: "text",
success: function(returnedData) {
      alert(returnedData);
    moveMarkerMap(returnedData);
}
});

}

function moveMarkerMap(newCoords) {
var newLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(newCoords);
map.panTo(newLatLang);
marker.setPosition(newLatLang);

}
window.setInterval(getCoords, 5000);
```

Setting the new google.maps.LatLng(14,41) in moveMarkerMap() will move it, and the returnedData shows in alert() but marker won't move when used with moveMarkerMap()

The returned string from ajax is correct format; (9.624672,7.242244) as shown in alert()
so not sure why its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google.maps.LatLng constructor takes two numbers for arguments.  This won't work:

```
var newLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(newCoords);
```

You need to convert newCoords into two numbers.

[Convert String to latlng google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778061/convert-string-to-latlng-google-maps)

[Convert “[52.43242, 4.43242]” to google LatLng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315722/convert-52-43242-4-43242-to-google-latlng)

[How do I get a pin on Google Maps using location from a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853530/how-do-i-get-a-pin-on-google-maps-using-location-from-a-variable)

Comment: The data returned by the ajax call is "13.444,98.7777" ... why wouldn't that work when I manually enter it ?

Comment: That is a single string, not two numbers.

Comment: I agree with that. Would have thought that worked tho, since all lat/lng coordinates are stored in that format :) thanks for pointing it out, i will try!

Comment: If others come across this problem, split the string:



success: function(returnedData) {
//        alert(returnedData);

        var coordsArray = returnedData.split(",");
        moveMarkerMap(coordsArray[0], coordsArray[1]);
}