# Google Map does not show the map with given langLat

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code to generate a Google Map based on the given latLang , but it does not show any map.

I get the latLang from DB and store it in a hidden input, the using `document.getElementById()` I get the value and assign it to the map. But it fails? Why?

```
(34.686298727073016, 50.92648297548294)
```

Here is the Javascript Code to Generate the map:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=fa"></script>
<div id='map-canvas' style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px;">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('mapPosition').value);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'منطقه مورد نظر در نقشه'
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "<B>نقطه مورد نظر خود را در نقشه کلیک کنید</B>"
  });
  /*
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      console.log(event);
      marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
      document.getElementById('mapPosition').value = event.latLng;
    map.setCenter(event.latLng);
  });*/
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item[0]['latLang']; ?>" name="mapPosition" id="mapPosition" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps move marker with lat/lng from ajax success returned data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654989/google-maps-move-marker-with-lat-lng-from-ajax-success-returned-data)

Answer (score 2):

[The api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) takes two arguments e.g.

```
new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
```

and it looks like you are passing it one

```
new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('mapPosition').value);
```

I would advise looking here for your problem.
Either parse the value

(34.686298727073016, 50.92648297548294)

into two parameters, or have two inputs- one for long and another for lat.

Comment: but I have saved it based on the given value by the google api itself....it seems I should use some sort of properties such as latLang.prop1, latLang.prop2   because the current value is saved from Google itself, I mean google uses this value itself

Comment: If I am not mistaken, document.getElementById('mapPosition').value returns a string representation not an object.

Answer (score 0):

try to give individual lat long values:

```
myLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long)
```