# Google Maps API V3 - map canvas loading, but with no visible tiles

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Basic idea, is an image map with two locations linked on it.

Clicking the location should load up a Google map showing that specific location in more detail

However, although I get the grey canvas loading, with Google logo, map/satellite etc. I am not getting any actual map tiles.

Tried using the solution from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404763/load-google-map-on-button-click-with-jquery)

No joy

Demo available [here](https://thehungryguest.com/contact-us/store-locations-old/) - click the lower left spot

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://thehungryguest.com/contact-us/store-locations-old/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://thehungryguest.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/THG-LocationMap.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the spot - sorted that, but still no tiles :(

Comment: currently you are loading the experimental API-version, for me the map works with the release-version( related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691295/google-maps-api-typeerror-a-is-undefined/32691543?noredirect=1#comment54165632_32691543 )

Comment: Thanks - that's sorted it.  Do you want to add an as answer, so I can rep you?

Comment: your related question sent me in the right direction, thanks @Dr.Molle and freestate