# Load google map onclick event

Tags: jquery, google-maps, onclick

I am using below code

```js
function displayMapAt_map2()
{
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["map"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Lat', 'Long', 'Name'],
          [-6.6,106.829635, 'Work'],
          [-6.6,106.859665, 'University'],
          [-6.6,106.849685, 'Airport'],
          [-6.6,106.839685, 'Shopping']
        ]);
 var options = {
   showTip: true,
   center: location,
   zoom: 2,
   mapType: 'normal',
   enableScrollWheel: true
 }

        var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas2'));
        map.draw(data,options);
      }
}
```

but this is not working for me

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: no. i just fire this event on click on <a href="#local" onClick="displayMapAt_map2">add</a>  but page gets reload

Comment: This question was already answered. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404763/load-google-map-on-button-click-with-jquery

Comment: but i am using different maps in three different tabs. and each map is with  multiple markers and long,lats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this. It helps me this way

```js
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["map"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Lat', 'Long', 'Name'],
          [-6.6,106.829635, 'Work'],
          [-6.6,106.859665, 'University'],
          [-6.6,106.849685, 'Airport'],
          [-6.6,106.839685, 'Shopping']
        ]);
 var options = {
   showTip: true,
   center: location,
   zoom: 2,
   mapType: 'normal',
   enableScrollWheel: true
 }

        var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas2'));
        map.draw(data,options);
      }
function displayMapAt_map2()
{
  drawChart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call like this,

```
 <a href="#local" onClick="displayMapAt_map2(event)">add</a>
```

Then on the function,

```
function displayMapAt_map2(e)
{
      e.preventDefault();
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["map"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Lat', 'Long', 'Name'],
          [-6.6,106.829635, 'Work'],
          [-6.6,106.859665, 'University'],
          [-6.6,106.849685, 'Airport'],
          [-6.6,106.839685, 'Shopping']
        ]);
    var options = {
      showTip: true,
      center: location,
      zoom: 2,
      mapType: 'normal',
      enableScrollWheel: true
    }

        var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas2'));
        map.draw(data,options);
      }
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me.  it reload the page infinitely :(

Comment: show us the html too. Did you refer google map js in your code?

Comment: <li role="presentation">
<a href="#local-pre" aria-controls="Products" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"  class="int-local-tab" onclick="displayMapAt_map2(event)"> MAP2</a> </li>

Comment: google js is added. this a tag is used to changing the tab. While changing the tab i need to call map function. but it get reload the whole page

Comment: put an alert in the function and checks if the function is getting called corrctly

Comment: what if I uncomment the mapscript?

Comment: the same. page get reload infinitely.

Comment: are you getting the alert when you uncomment the mapscript??

Comment: Man , then there must be some console errors. check the console first.

Comment: When the page get reloads then console get clear. How can i see if there is any error

Comment: Sorry. but i cross checked. There is not any error in console