# Google map API Directions - Issue with variable

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can display the directions between two points using google api as follows:-

```
    if (e.keyCode == 109 && $("#booking-docket").dialog("isOpen")) {

      var pickup = $('#txt-pickup-lat-long').val();
      var destination = $('#txt-destination-lat-long').val();

      alert(pickup);
      alert(destination);

      var start = new google.maps.LatLng(52.73696,-1.3553244444444);
      var end = new google.maps.LatLng(52.781048888889,-1.2110222222222);
      var request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });

    }
```

- alert(pickup) = 52.73696,-1.3553244444444
- alert(destination) = 52.781048888889,-1.2110222222222

However, when I change these values from:-

```
      var start = new google.maps.LatLng(52.73696,-1.3553244444444);
      var end = new google.maps.LatLng(52.781048888889,-1.2110222222222);
```

to:-

```
      var start = new google.maps.LatLng(pickup);
      var end = new google.maps.LatLng(destination);
```

It stops working, even though the values of pickup & destination are exactly the same as what is typed in (without using variables).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps move marker with lat/lng from ajax success returned data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654989/google-maps-move-marker-with-lat-lng-from-ajax-success-returned-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that *pickup* and *destination* are strings, which is what the jQuery `.val()` function returns.

The [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) constructor expects floats.  Wrap your pickup and destination values in parseFloat to convert them from string to floats.

In fact as they're actually a list, each containing two items, you'll need to split them into their two separate parts first as well.

```js
var pickup = $('#txt-pickup-lat-long').val();
var pickupLat = pickup.split(",")[0];
var pickupLng = pickup.split(",")[1];
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(pickupLat), parseFloat(pickupLng));
```