# Create a loop from a chain to draw Polyline on Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I can't succeed to draw on my Google map a polyline with a loop. One of my coworker fill different coordinates separate by a "/". I'd like to split it and make a loop in Maps.

**Here is what i want to have at the end :**

```
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
     new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
     new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
  ];
```

**Here is what I have :**

```
37.772323, -122.214897/21.291982, -157.821856/-18.142599, 178.431
```

**Here is my code so far :**

```
var coord_itineraire = '37.772323, -122.214897/21.291982, -157.821856/-18.142599, 178.431';
cut_itineraire = coord_itineraire.split("/");
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
$.each(cut_itineraire, function(index, valeur_coord) {
      return ("new google.maps.LatLng("+valeur_coord+"), ");
})
];
```

But here is the problem my console shows :

> InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Infos : To make it simple here I just put the numbers, normally "coord_itineraire" is a variable which take the value recorded in the BO of my website. It could be only 3 point like here, or 20, it's never fixed.

I tried a parseFloat on my "valeur_coord" but the second number of the row is erased.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps move marker with lat/lng from ajax success returned data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654989/google-maps-move-marker-with-lat-lng-from-ajax-success-returned-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
        var coord_itineraire = '37.772323, -122.214897/21.291982, -157.821856/-18.142599, 178.431';
        var coord_itineraire_arr = coord_itineraire.split("/");
        var flightPlanCoordinates = [];

        for ( var key in coord_itineraire_arr ) {
            var temp = coord_itineraire_arr[key].split(",");
            flightPlanCoordinates.push( new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat( temp[0] ) , parseFloat( temp[1] ) ) );
        }
```

This will result to:

```
 var flightPlanCoordinates = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
     new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
     new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are building a string, not an array of LatLng object.

Please check this code :

```
var coord_itineraire = "37.772323, -122.214897/21.291982, -157.821856/-18.142599, 178.431";
var cut_itineraire = coord_itineraire.split("/");

//Empty array
var flightPlanCoordinates = [];

$.each(cut_itineraire, function(index, valeur_coord) {
  var coords = valeur_coord.split(', ');
  var lat = parseFloat(coords[0]);
  var lng = parseFloat(coords[1])
  flightPlanCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng))
});

console.log(flightPlanCoordinates)
```

Don't hesitate to ask a question if you have problem

Comment: Ah i didn't think about making a second split in the each to separate the lat and the lng !! Genius ! thanks !